# Rectangle Appears Distorted on Map

Tags: postgis, geojson, openlayers-2

When displaying two features, a polygon `a` (see [geoJSON](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ktraff/45dae43d750886b88541/raw/2ed8feb9e0d91bbecebf6d3225f285b1ecf63d7e/gistfile1.txt)) and its minimum bounding rectangle `b` (see [geoJSON](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ktraff/28af6e671d070d0ebb0d/raw/25549f0380710d668981524cfee2ef7c7f90c0ab/gistfile1.txt)), I get the [following result](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac09cb6f105d514ef768) when viewing on geojson.io:

[image]

The minimum bounding rectangle around the polygon looks more like a parallelogram than a rectangle to me.

However, when I upload these same features to OpenLayers, the distortion is gone:

[image]

Is this a projection issue?

Comment: It certainly looks like a projection issue. What spatial reference are you viewing it i? The second window looks like geographic... are your source features geographic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a projection issue. OpenLayers defaults to geographic coordinates (lat/lon) so a simple "show me the thing" with it will paint it in geographics. GeoJSON.io wants to overlay things on top of web-mercator maps, so it reprojects your data into mercator, which stretches things out at the poles, just as you are seeing.